# Screen suddenly appearing white

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I'm working on a project where I want to add quotes to images. I set up my storyboard which worked fine.

Now I added the ability to add images to the UICollectionView. This worked perfectly as well but for some reason after some changes when I start the app a white screen appears only.

You can see my [project here on GitHub](https://github.com/revil4/Quotify)

Here is my code of the NewImagesCollectionViewController if you don't want to download the app:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "newImageCell"

class NewImagesCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

var newImageCollection:[UIImage] = []

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    collectionView?.reloadData()
    print(newImageCollection)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if newImageCollection.count > 0 {
        return newImageCollection.count
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewImagesCollectionViewCell
    cell.newImageView.image = newImageCollection[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

//MARK: Adding Images
@IBAction func addPicturesPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    print("didfinishpicking")
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        print("ADD pickedImage!")
        newImageCollection.append(pickedImage)
    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with this line:

```
collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

In your `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method.

Just comment it and check.

Comment: Happy to help you..:)